# It is possible to send emails with CakeMail without specifying sender password?

Tags: sendmail, cakephp-2.0

I'm developing on CakePHP 2.0.

I'm using CakeMail to send some notification emails.

However, this is for a client.. this emails should be sent from "subscriptions@client.com".

It is necessary to specify that email account pswd? --> I don't want to ask the client for his pswd/

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. If the application is running on a server that has access to the Mail transport (traditional LAMP stack), you can use the `$default` in the mail config and it will send it using the mail transport.

If you are using a remote email account to send mail through (i.e. gmail), you will need the password or the remote server will not allow mail to be sent. Imagine the spam nightmares a remote email server would have if it just let anyone send mail from it without a password.